# Apache SOLR Error

Tags: php, drupal, solr, drupal-7

I'm trying to work with SOLR on our Drupal 7 server, but I keep getting an error and I don't know what it means:

> Exception: HTTP 400; orgapachelucenequeryParserParseException_Cannot_parse__AND_sm_field_product_type_TO__AND__OR_sm_field_product_type1_Encountered_____at_line_1_column_1_Was_expecting_one_of_____NOT______________________________QUOTED______TERM______PREFIXTERM______WILDTERM__________________NUMBER______TERM____________: orgapachelucenequeryParserParseException_Cannot_parse__AND_sm_field_product_type_TO__AND__OR_sm_field_product_type1_Encountered_____at_line_1_column_1_Was_expecting_one_of_____NOT______________________________QUOTED______TERM______PREFIXTERM______WILDTERM__________________NUMBER______TERM____________ in DrupalApacheSolrService->checkResponse() (line 455 of /vagrant/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/apachesolr/Drupal_Apache_Solr_Service.php).
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Does anyone know what the error means and how I would go about resolving it?

Comment: Is there *any* chance that you pasted the error into Google?

Comment: What is the query here, in which parsing is failing? Also AND and OR are Boolean operator in Lucene. You might need to escape them while querying.